# jQuery: обработка AJAX ответа и ошибки

Tags: php, jquery

```
<script>
    var requestData = {
        vote: "15"
    }

    $(".vote").click(function(e)
    {
        $.get("sendToThispage", requestData, serverResponse, "json");
        e.preventDefault();
    });

    function serverResponse(data)
    {
        $(".file-data").text(data.votes);
    }
</script>
```

Голосуем за ID файла N 15 при получении ответа заменяем данные в div классе `.file-data`.

Сервер отвечает так

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query($query))
{
    header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
    $data = [
          'votes' => $result->fetch_row()[0]
    ];
    echo json_encode($data);
}
else
    $notice = 'Ошибка при запросе в бд';
if (isset($notice))
{
   header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8");
   $data = [
      'notice' => $notice
   ];
   echo json_encode($data);
}
```

при ошибке хорошо бы показать ее

```
<div class="notice">Ошибка при запросе в бд</div>
```

Подскажите, как поправить jQuery чтобы он изменял `.file-data` при успешном запрос (это уже сделал), но при ошибке показывал `.notice` и внутри ошибку (по умолчанию `.notice` спрятан ), а `.file-data` не трогал?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Просто надо проверить свойства полученного объекта и на основе факта их наличия или отсутствия выполнить те или иные действия.

```
function serverResponse(data)
{
  if (data.notice) {
    $(".notice").html(data.notice).show();  // вставить данные и показать элемент
  }
  else {
    $(".file-data").html(data.votes);
  {
}
```

Также можно вызывать `$(".notice").hide()`, когда надо скрыть элемент. Можно еще оперировать свойством `display` : `$(".notice").css('display', 'block');`

И еще: повесьте обработчик на неудачу запроса

```
$.get("sendToThispage", requestData, serverResponse, "json").fail(function() {
    alert("Все сломалось");
});
```

[Ссылка на документацию](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/)

UPD1:

Если на странице нет элемента `div.notice`, то его надо просто создать вставить

```
$('div.title').after('<div class="notice"></div>');
```

А уже изменять его содержимое. Хотя я бы его просто создал по умолчанию, просто сделал бы невидимым:

```
<div class="notice" style="display: none"></div>
```

UPD2:

Чтобы проверить есть ли элемент на странице нужно сделать следующее:

```
if ($(".notice").length) alert("Есть элемент");
else alert("Нет элемента");
```

Чтобы узнать показывается элемент (предполагаем что он существует) надо проверить css свойство `display`

```
if ($(".notice").css("display") === "none") alert("Элемент скрыт");
else alert("Элемент отображается");
```

[Работа с css через jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: RussCoder `div.notice` отсутствует на странице при ее первоначальной загрузке, а данные отправляются и принимаются без перезагрузки страницы. Требуется показать `div.notice` сразу после `did.title`, последний выводится при первоначальной загрузке, как тут быть?

Comment: При использовании `$('div.title').after('<div class="notice"></div>');` и нажатии на кнопку голосования, при существующей ошибке, div.notice дублируется. Видимо лучше использовать `display: none`. Скажите, пожалуйста, если, к примеру, вывелась ошибка и при повторном клике ее уже нет, то чтобы спрятать нужно проверить висит ли окошко с ошибкой. После условия else пишем  `if (div.notice = показывается) { $(".notice").hide(); }` Какое тут `if` условие использовать?

Comment: @Plush обновил ответ.

Comment: @Plush вы затеяли интересную вещь, вследствии которой я узнал о новых особенностях сайта )), а именно http://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/serial-voting-reversed

Comment: RussCoder, благодарю, я о них раньше не знал.

Answer (score 1):

```
function serverResponse(data)
{
  if (data.notice)
    $(".notice").text(data.notice);
  else
    $(".file-data").text(data.votes);
}
```